# Identify Toggle Layers with Attachments

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, html, attachments

I was looking at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/neWnE/1/ and trying to see get attachments to work.

Since it uses the popuptemplate I should be able to add the showAttachments: true to it to get attachments to show in the popup window correct?

```
var template = new PopupTemplate({
        title : "Name: {NAME}",
        fieldInfos : [{
          fieldName : "ADDRESS",
          visible : true,
          label : "Address:"
        }],
        showAttachments: true
      });
```

I replaced the map services in the fiddle with my own that I enabled attachments on but they aren't appearing.

Is there something else that I would need to do?